# How to do a repair install of SCVMM 2008 R2?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, scvmm

We tried to install SCVMM 2008 R2 on a server last week. The C: drive at that time did not have enough space to contain SCVMM and continue to run server operations, shortly after the install we were forced to manually delete the SCVMM folder in Program Files.

We have since cleaned things up and have plenty of space available, but now we can't get SCVMM Server to install because it thinks it's already installed. We have tried msiexec /faum VmmServer.msi but it looks like the installer forces you to use the GUI (/q flags for msiexec don't seem to make any difference).

We need to either: clean up the registry entries from the previous install (not preferred, there are probably a lot), or repair the previous SCVMM install (preferred). How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `msizap.exe` from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370834(v=vs.85).aspx.

In an elevated command line:

`msizap T E:\amd64\msi\Server\vmmServer.msi`

This left only a sort-of zombie service that doesn't show up in `sc query` but is visible in *services.msc*. To remove, enter this at a command prompt:

`sc delete vmmserver`

After a reboot, I was able to re-install without issue.